# django create a field that hold array of tupels or array of array

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

I want to add a field in my models that hold value like this

```
field = [(1,2,3),(6,5,4),(5,6,7)]

            or

field = [[1,2,3],[6,5,4],[5,6,7]]
```

I am using postgresql db. how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

In django [`docs`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield) , its stated as:

```py
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField
from django.db import models

class Board(models.Model):
    pieces = ArrayField(ArrayField(models.IntegerField()))

# Valid
Board(pieces=[
    [2, 3],
    [2, 1],
])
```